# Как в VBA Excel выделить цветом n-случайных ячеек

Tags: excel, случайные-числа, vba

Нужно в Excel на листе в выделенном диапазоне залить желтым цветом случайным образом 5 ячеек.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RndColor()
    Dim SelectedRange  As Range
    Dim CountCells As Long, RndCell As Long, i As Long
    
    Randomize
     
    Set SelectedRange = Selection
    CountCells = SelectedRange.Count
    
    If CountCells <= 5 Then
        SelectedRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To 5
        RndCell = Int(CountCells * Rnd + 1)
        SelectedRange(RndCell).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Без проверки на повтор ячейки

Answer (score 0):

Без повторов

```
Option Explicit

Sub Paint5RND()
    With Selection
        If .Cells.Count < 5 Then Exit Sub ' если ячеек меньше 5, ничего не красим (можно настроить по-другому)
        Dim cl As Range, rng As Range, i As Long, idx As Long, col As New Collection
        For Each cl In .Cells: col.Add cl: Next 'заносим все ячейки выбранной области (смежные и несмежные) в коллекцию
        For i = 1 To 5 
            idx = Int(col.Count * Rnd + 1) ' формируем случайный индекс внутри коллекции
            Set cl = col(idx) ' забираем ячейку по индексу
            col.Remove idx ' удаляем элемент из коллекции, чтобы не было повторов
            If rng Is Nothing Then  ' формируем диапазон из выбранных ячеек
                Set rng = cl
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, cl)
            End If
        Next
        rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow ' красим все отобранные ячейки за 1 операцию
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Randomize` обидели :) Не надо игнорировать.